# Why Do Java Files Not Run If I don't have a folder open in VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am new to Java, and wanted to get started in VSCode. I ran my first Java file only to see that the terminal didn't open. Like it had the little run thingy on the top but the terminal didn't open and I couldn't see my file working.

I had happened to my .java file in some folder than uploaded that to VSCode, then ran that and that worked. Then I tried to run a .java file in VSCode even if it wasn't in the uploaded file, and that worked too. But when I close the uploaded folder and try to run the .java file and yeah it didn't work. Help please?

Comment: One way of figuring it out whether vsc is at fault or your code, is to run the javac and java command on that file.

Comment: I can reproduce your question, can you open an issue in [github/vscode-java](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues)?

Comment: Should be a regression and will be fixed in the next release: https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/2231